# Validate Python Fme

Tags: python, fme-form

i have a problem with my script for convert GDB to Excel.

```py
if s=='xls':
    reader=FMEReader("GEODATABASE_FILE")
    reader.open(param_filename_gdb)
    writerXls= FMEWriter("XLS_ADO")
    new_schema = export + "Excel\\" + filenameGDB + ".xls"
    writerXls.open(new_schema)
            
    schemaXls=FMEFeature()
    
    while reader.readSchema(schemaXls):
        log.logFeature(schemaXls)
        writerXls.addSchema(schemaXls)
    
    features=FMEFeature()
    
    while reader.read(features):
        log.logFeature(features)
        writerXls.write(features)
           
    reader.close() 
    writerXls.close()
```

The creation of my Xls works but the logger of FME tell me:

> MS Excel Writer: Connection failed.
> Connection string Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=null;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=YES". Provider error The table is not in the expected format.
> Failed to open writer

But the logger tell:

> MS Excel Writer: Closing `C:\Excel\test2.xls' . **Write operation complete**

The code is in Startup Python Script.

Comment: It is not FME it is Excel - please read - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298726/accessing-excel-spreadsheet-with-c-occasionally-returns-blank-value-for-some-cel

Comment: It's very strange because the same code in PythonCreator works very well !!!

Comment: I think the more relevant question is why you are using a script to convert GDB to Excel? FME will let you do this much more easily in a workspace - then you can run that workspace programmatically if you need to, passing in parameters as required. Check out my blog post on the subject at: http://evangelism.safe.com/fmeevangelist69/

Comment: Because it's a dynamic workbench and it's very fast with Python...